# Why does “you are the fairest here so true” mean not the fairest?

Tags: meaning, so

In Snow White, the magic mirror first response to the Evil Queen is

> My Queen, you are the fairest in the land.

Then

> My Queen, you are the fairest here so true. But Snow White is a thousand times more beautiful than you.

Then

> My Queen, you are the fairest here so true. But Snow White beyond the mountains at the seven Dwarfs is a thousand times more beautiful than you.

And then

> You, my Queen, are fair so true. But the young Queen is a thousand times fairer than you.

I think it is because of **here** that makes **so true** not true. In the last response, there is no **here**, but **fair** is used instead.
Does **so true** mean **not true**?

Answer (score 1):

> Does so true mean not true?

No. The expression "so true" is a bit odd, but if it's interpreted as "very true", then you can understand.

Consider these similar sentences:

"My Queen, you are the fairest here (in this village), very true."
"But Snow White beyond the mountains (far away), is more beautiful."

Comment: That clears me up.